# MySQL: Creating query that sums column while gathering info from other tables

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

List the Rider's Name, RaceLevel as
Race_Level and the total number of all points based on their placement. Make sure that you don't
list any riders who have not raced in any races yet (not placed yet). Sort the data from highest to
lowest total points

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT RIDERS.FIRST_NAME, RIDERS.LAST_NAME, RACES.RACE_LEVEL, PARTICIPATION.PLACEMENT
FROM RIDERS, RACES, PARTICIPATION
WHERE RIDERS.RIDER_ID = PARTICIPATION.RIDER_ID AND RACES.RACE_LEVEL = 'EASY' AND PARTICIPATION.PLACEMENT > 0;
```

I've tried adding `SUM(PARTICIPATION.PLACEMENT)` but it removes all results and leaves me with one line. I need to figure out how to sum placement for each individual.

Comment: You need to study `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried adding SUM(PARTICIPATION.PLACEMENT) but it removes all results and leaves me with one line.

You need a `group by` clause to make this a valid aggregation query:

```
select ri.first_name, ri.last_name, ra.race_level, sum(pa.placement)
from riders ri
inner join participation pa on ri.rider_id = pa.rider_id
inner join races ra on ??
where ra.race_level = 'easy' and pa.placement > 0
group by ri.rider_id, ri.first_name, ri.last_name, ra.race_level
```

Important notes:

- Use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause) are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code. I modified your code, and now it is plain to see that you are missing a join condition on the `race` table; you did not provide enough information for me to make an educated guess, so I represented that as `??` in the query
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- adding the primary key of the `riders` table in the `group by` clause ensures that the query won't wrongly group together different riders that would have the same name